# React js, which methods should I avoid to achieve an optimal performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to know what are the methods or process (related to recomputations during each render)  that I should avoid in order to improve the performance of my code. I'm not asking about good coding practices like avoid spaghetti code, but specifically functions or process.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is way too broad. But I can provide a couple of hints from experience.

Consider using a library like Reselect (https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to avoid recomputations during each render. This concept is similar to computed properties in other UI frameworks.

Do not abuse `PureComponent` class and `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method, if you are still using class based components. `useMemo` is a similar hook for functional components. They should be used to solve a specific performance problem however they can lead to subtle bugs if used without thinking it through. A lot of times renders in virtual DOM are not that expensive.

Use React Developer Tools extension to determine if there is actually a performance problem.